# IF/ELSE on Javascript works strangely

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, html, forms

I have a form where I ask for an email that I validate trought a regular expression, if the email is correct, I do a submit, if not I send an alert.

When I put an invalid email the alert is shown, but if I put a valid email the alert is shown and then the submit() is done, I don't even know how is this posible! Here is my code.

```
$('#sinCopago').on('click', function(event){
    if($('#nombreContratante').val() != "" && $('#motivo').val() != ""){
        if($('#fechaNac').val() > hoy){
            alert("Ingresa una fecha de nacimiento válida.");
        }else{
            if(validarMail($("#correo")) == true){
                event.preventDefault();
                $('#progressBarSisnova').modal({show:true});
                $('#payment-form-Sisnova').submit();
            }
            else{
                alert("Ingresa un correo válido");
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        alert("Por favor llene todos los campos");
    }
});

function validarMail(email){
    var caract = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/;

    if(caract.test(email) == false){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Handling the click will not prevent the form submission, unless you either a) add `event.preventDefault();` to your function or b) return false from it.

Comment: Offtopic, but dude, try to keep a pattern. At some places you have the `else` on the same line as the closing brackets from if, other places you break line. It makes your code hard to read

Comment: Your regular expression is too restrictive.  See [this answer about validating email addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/361684).  Personally, I prefer to check for `.@.`, followed by a DNS request for an MX record at the specified domain.  If both of those pass, I assume the address is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently passing the `$("#correo")` jQuery object to `validarMail`:

```
if(validarMail($("#correo")) == true){
```

and proceed to test *that object*:

```
if(caract.test(email) == false){
```

Which won't work, of course, because you're not testing a string. Try passing the `.val()` of `#correo` instead. so that the eventual `.test(` is called with the *value string*, not the jQuery object:

```
if(validarMail($("#correo").val()) == true){
```

Feel free to remove the `== true` part, `validarMail` already returns a boolean:

```
if(validarMail($("#correo").val())){
```

You should also `preventDefault` *when the test fails*, not when the test succeeds - that way, the form will be submitted as normal without interruption only when the test succeeds. The code will also probably be flatter and easier to read if you `return` when there's an error:

```
$('#sinCopago').on('click', function(event){
  if($('#nombreContratante').val() === "" || $('#motivo').val() === "") {
    event.preventDefault();
    return alert("Por favor llene todos los campos");
  }
  if($('#fechaNac').val() <= hoy){
    event.preventDefault();
    return alert("Ingresa una fecha de nacimiento válida.");
  }
  if(!validarMail($("#correo").val())){
    event.preventDefault();
    return alert("Ingresa un correo válido");
  }
  $('#progressBarSisnova').modal({show:true});
  $('#payment-form-Sisnova').submit();
});
```

If clicking `#sinCopago` submits the form without `preventDefault`, then there's no need for the final line there `$('#payment-form-Sisnova').submit();`. (Otherwise, then there may be no need for `preventDefault` at all, if the event's default action doesn't cause a form submission or other undesirable behavior)

Comment: So I guess we can close this as typo?

Answer (score 1):

you should pass the value of field for function `validarMail()`, so replace the current cod

```
if(validarMail($("#correo")) == true)
```

for

```
 if(validarMail($("#correo").val()) == true)
```

an you can improve you function.

```
function validarMail(email){
    var caract = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/;
    return caract.test(email)    
}
```